# Merge multiple files containing same IDs - Linux

Tags: search, awk, merge, grep, cat

i have 10000 files in One folder like this :

- 1000.htm
- Page_1000.html
- file-1000.txt
- 2000.htm
- Page_2000.html
- file-2000.txt

i want merge each files that have similar name

```
example :
1000.htm Page_1000.html file-1000.txt > 1.txt
2000.htm Page_2000.html file-2000.txt > 2.txt
```

i have try to merge using **cat** like this its working but i cant do that in 10k files.

```
cat 1000* > 1.txt 
cat 2000* > 2.txt
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You probably can't do that because the globbing (*) tries to expand to a too large amount of argument. You can use find instead to find all files matching the pattern and than use xargs to perform cat on them.

```
find . -name '1000*' -print0 | xargs -0 cat > 1.txt
```

'-print0' and '-0' will delimit on the null (\0) character instead of the default line break character (\n). This way also files with linebreaks in their file names work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

```
find . -name '*.htm' -printf '%P\n' |
while IFS='.' read -r key sfx; do
    cnt=$(( cnt + 1 ))
    cat "${key}.htm" "Page_${key}.html" "file-${key}.txt" > "${cnt}.txt"
done
```

though you should consider using the key in the output file name instead of a cnt variable so it's easy to tell which input files were included in the output file.

Answer (score 0):

```
i=1;
for ((num = 1000; num < 10000; num+=1000));
do 
cat ${num}.htm Page_${num}.html file-${num}.txt > ${i}.txt
i=$((i + 1));
done
```

You can change num < 10000, as per your requirement.